# Enviar email vb6 o .net

Tags: email, vb6

Hace varios años que tengo una aplicación en vb6 que enviaba emails. Desde hace un tiempo, da error al enviar ( "Error en el transporte de datos"). He intentado con MAPI, CDO y vbsendmail, sin obtener éxito.
Me gustaría saber si alguien consiguió solucionar el problema.

Les pongo aquí el código de mi último intento:

```
 
    On Error GoTo SendMail_Error:
    Dim lobj_cdomsg      As CDO.Message
    Set lobj_cdomsg = New CDO.Message
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPServer) = sSmtpServer
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPServerPort) = iSmtpPort
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = bSmtpSSL
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPAuthenticate) = cdoBasic
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSendUserName) = sSmtpUser
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSendPassword) = sSmtpPword
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPConnectionTimeout) = 30
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort
    lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields.Update
    lobj_cdomsg.To = sTo
    lobj_cdomsg.From = sFrom
    lobj_cdomsg.Subject = sSubject
    lobj_cdomsg.TextBody = sBody
    If Trim$(sFilePath) <> vbNullString Then
        lobj_cdomsg.AddAttachment (sFilePath)
    End If
    lobj_cdomsg.Send
    Set lobj_cdomsg = Nothing
    SendMail = "ok"
    Exit Function
 
SendMail_Error:
    SendMail = Err.Description
```

Todo lo que leo (y llevo meses investigando) siempre me lleva a que YA no se puede enviar por smtp desde vb6, por cuestiones de autenticación (SSL), y me gustaría saber si alguien se encontró con este problema. La idea de migrar a .NET no es posible con esta aplicación.
También he probado a hacer una página en .NET sólo para enviar emails, y por parámetros, pasarle los datos, con este código:

```
x = ShellExecute(Me.hwnd, "Open", "https://mipaginaweb/enviarmail.aspx?DES=" & destino & " &ASU=" & Asunto & " &CUE=" & cuerpo & "", &O0, &O0, SW_NORMAL)
```

Pero no consigo poner retornos de carro, ni texto formateado...

¿Alguien puede darme una ayuda?
Muchas gracias, por adelantado.

Comment: Hola, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Hola ¿El correo que usas es de Gmail? Confirma eso o no.

Comment: Hola. Mi servidor es propio, pero también probé la configuración de Gmail, con los puertos 587 , 465, 25. Siempre obtengo "Error en el transporte de datos "

Comment: oh bueno, lo pregunté porque las políticas de seguridad de Gmail, así como correos que usan servidores Google (así no sean de Gmail), han cambiado y se debe usar otra clave, pero si usas uno propio con tu propio dominio, no es eso.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios. He leído que CDO está obsoleto, porque no admite autenticación TLS. Pero NO quiero rendirme. Tiene que haber algún componente que envíe emails desde vb6. Las personas que se encontraron este problema, ¿cómo consiguieron solucionarlo? me cuesta mucho creer que migrasen toda una aplicación en vb6 sólo porque no funcione el smtp. ¿alguna ayudita, porfa?

Comment: Hasta ahora estoy usando el control MAPI, y lo curioso, es que con el mismo código, a unos usuarios les funciona, y a otros les da error al enviar los correos ("48389 - Ocurrió un error al enviar el Email").

Comment: Prueba cambiando esta línea:   lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields(cdoSMTPUseSSL) = bSmtpSSL  

Por esta otra: lobj_cdomsg.Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendtls").Value = True

Comment: He cambiado la línea, y el resultado es otro error: "No se pudo enviar el mensaje al servidor SMTP El código de error de transporte fue 0x80040217. La respuesta del servidor fue not available".

Comment: Lo siento, es complicado ayudarte mejor sin tener el proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por todo, Abraham

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, acabo de encontrar la solución, el problema no está en tu código, hay q configurar una contraseña de aplicaciones en gmail.

te dejo el link

https://practicaprende.com/12-macro-para-enviar-correos-gmail-desde-excel/

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/375810)

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, bienvenido, no hay que apresurarse a contestar, si lees los comentarios, descubrirás que Magda no usa Gmail, por lo que tu respuesta no es correcta, te sugiero eliminarla para evitar recibir votos negativos, de paso te invito a hacer el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!